# Get BaseColumn Of a ViewColumn

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, metadata

Assume this view:

```
SELECT
 [Pr].[Id],
 [Pr].[Title],
 [Pr].[Category_Id] AS [CategoryId],
 [Pr].[IsScanAllowed],
 [Pr].[MaxLevelOfRegistration],
 [Cat].[Title] AS [Category],
 [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] AS [MajorCategoryId],
 [Mc].[Title] AS [MajorCategory]
 [Cat].[Title]+[Pr].[Title] AS [FullProduct]
FROM [Products].[Product] AS [Pr]
INNER JOIN [Products].[Category] AS [Cat] ON [Pr].[Category_Id] = [Cat].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Products].[MajorCategory] AS [Mc] ON [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] = [Mc].[Id];
```

So is there any way to find base column of each this view's columns, except `[FullProduct]` that is a calculated column all of other columns have a base column. Something like this: `BaseOf(MajorCategoryId) is [Products].[MajorCategory].[Id]` I try to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` but I can't find anything, does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know that since it isn't passed back to the client, but you can construct your column names to show it -- like this:

```
SELECT
 [Pr].[Id] AS [Products_Id],
 [Pr].[Title] AS [Products_Title],
 [Pr].[Category_Id] AS [Products_CategoryId],
 [Pr].[IsScanAllowed] AS [Products_IsScanAllowed],
 [Pr].[MaxLevelOfRegistration] [Products_MaxLevelOfRegistration],
 [Cat].[Title] AS [Category_Title],
 [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] AS [Category_MajorCategoryId],
 [Mc].[Title] AS [MajorCategory_Title]
 [Cat].[Title]+[Pr].[Title] AS [FullProduct]
FROM [Products].[Product] AS [Pr]
INNER JOIN [Products].[Category] AS [Cat] ON [Pr].[Category_Id] = [Cat].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Products].[MajorCategory] AS [Mc] ON [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] = [Mc].[Id];
```

Then to see the table you can take first item in the split on `_`.

---

You can also download the source of the view using SQL metadata, and parse it, but that seems like a lot of work to me.